# Can I add new fields to default tables generated by Identity 2.0 in MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

Can I go to database and add new fields to default tables generated by Identity 2.0 in MVC 5. I want to add few fields to ASPnetRoles. I know I can first add fields to table in database and then do "update model from Database..". I just want to make sure it won't create any other problems.

Comment: Just want to add that by changing database table directly and then updating model and controller, view etc, its working good. Still not sure if this is the right way to do for Database first approach. love to hear more from experts. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can add fields to the tables with identity 2.0: [see this tutorial to know how to extend Identity user](http://typecastexception.com/post/2014/06/22/ASPNET-Identity-20-Customizing-Users-and-Roles.aspx#Extending-Identity-User---The-Easy-Part)

You just have to change the ApplicatuionUser class (for instance) and then the changed model will be re-created in DB (Entity Framewok Code-First). 
 - Add fields in ApplicationUser class

Make attention to the ApplicationDbInitializer, it is set to DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges by default, so if you don't want to loose all your DB if model change (and indeed, model will change if you add a field to the User Class) , change DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges  to CreateDatabaseIfNotExists for instance.

Then after, you have to change the business and UI code for instance :

1. Update the Register ViewModel to Include new fields
2. Update the Register View to Include
3. Update the Register Method on AccountController

Comment: You should provide more detail in your answer rather than relying entirely on a link.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am going to study that. But can I not just add fields to table in database directly and update the model?? Then I can handle new field in controller etc as I want.

Comment: @ary : no, this is Entty Framewok Code First, you should make the change in the code then ASP.NET will know that difference and then re-create the model that you creade in code into the database!

Comment: Thanks. But I created my project using EF Database First. Can I still not create the fields in database first?

Comment: @ary You can create entities with EF db first for your project, or you can do ADO.NET, or what you want, but Identity 2.0 use Code first. Try what I suggest, and you can keep the DB first for the rets of the application. You can mix EF code firdst, EF DB first, you can also use a service layer, you can also use ADO.NET on the same projets, there is no problem about that.

Comment: @ary but if you really want to use DB first approach (I repeat, this is not the default one), there is a example projetc o hw to use this approach on the https://github.com/kriasoft/AspNet.Identity or on http://danieleagle.com/blog/2014/05/setting-up-asp-net-identity-framework-2-0-with-database-first-vs2013-update-2-spa-template/